# Disable page curl animation in Lion's iCal

Tags: macos, ical

I can live with the skeuomorphic skin of the new iCal, but the useless page curl animation when switching months is both slow and jittery. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [iCal-Classic-Page-Flip](https://github.com/lukele/iCal-Classic-Page-Flip) (via [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40293/ical-classic-page-flip)):

> ## iCal Classic Page Flip
>
> The solution to Apples very slooow Page-Flip animation for monthly and yearly view in iCal 5.
>
> iCal Classic Page Flip is a little SIMBL plugin for those of us who are frustrated by the very slow page animation in the latest version of iCal (the one that comes with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion). Both Monthly and Yearly views both have an animation of a turning page, which might be nice on the first look, but it's time consuming and slows down the work flow on the long run.
>
> This software is the solution. It disables the painfully slow animation of the latest iCal version and gives you back fast navigation in iCal. Now again, you can use cmd + arrows to move to the next / previous month or year in iCal blazingly fast.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, holding Option down with the keyboard shortcuts doesn't work (iCal just beeps at you), but you can change the keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences to include the Option key, then it'll work.

For example, I changed the shortcut for "Next" from Cmd-Right Arrow to Cmd-Option-Right Arrow and changed "Previous" to Cmd-Option-Left Arrow. Now the keyboard shortcuts will navigate without the annoying page flip animation.

To do this, go to System Preferences, Keyboard, Keyboard Shortcuts, Application Shortcuts, then hit the "+" icon, and enter the following details - Application: iCal, Menu Title: "Next", Keyboard Shortcut: Cmd-Option-Right Arrow. Then hit "+" again and enter Application: iCal, Menu Title: "Previous", Keyboard Shortcut: Cmd-Option-Left Arrow.

Answer (score 5):

Press "alt" key (⌥) while clicking on the arrows.

And for the pattern there is LionBleacher 1.0 out now for free.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39514/lionbleacher

Comment: Nice find. Now maybe someone can hack something to reverse the behavior without having to press ⌥.

Comment: I hope so too. The new page curl animation is annoyingly slow.